# Converting anonymous type to another anonymous type

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection

I wrote a library that can serialize LINQ expressions to a byte array. A server can receive and reconstruct the query from the serialized data, plug in the appropriate data sources, and return the result to the client. The library supports projection to anonymous types. When the query is de-serialized, it reconstructs the anonymous `RuntimeType` by emitting the appropriate IL. When the client receives the result, there's an expectation that the type can be accessed using the anonymous type's properties.

E.g.

```cs
var query = Customers
   .Where(c => c.State == "CO")
   .Select(c => new { c.Id, c.FirstName, c.LastName });

var results = query.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

foreach(var result in results)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"{c.Id} = {c.FirstName} {c.LastName}";
}
```

The underlying query provider can't present the result because the anonymous type created by IL emit is not the same type as what was defined in the query and so `List<<>__anonymous1>` is not convertible to `List<<>__anonymous2>. Therefore the type needs to be converted. The *CastByExample* trick here won't work because the type's aren't in the same assembly.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: IMHO, write an `ExpressionVisitor` to substitute parts of the supplied `.Select(...)` expression tree, client side. Dropping in expressions that supply the values you are deserialising from the server. Then compile it. That's basically what EF Core would do for sql queries.

Comment: Only the server sees the de-serialized query, the client only receives the result. Am I understanding your suggestion correctly?

Comment: A more concrete example. So client side you do this transformation; `c => new { c.Id, c.FirstName, c.LastName }` => `result => new { Id = result.get("Id"), FirstName = result.get("FirstName"), ... }`.  Then the client receives `result` from the server. And the server doesn't need to know anything about the client's anonymous type.

Comment: I see now - the example put it all together. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There's two options here:

1. Out-of-the box, [Automapper](https://automapper.org/) does this.
2. The mapping can be performed by leveraging expression trees:

```cs
public static Func<object, TResult> CreateAnonymousTypeMapper<TResult>(Type srcType)
{
    /* Produces the following equivalent in delegate form:
     * TResult Convert(object obj)
     * {
     *      var source = (SourceType)obj;
     *      return new TResult(source.Property1, source.Property2, ...);
     * }
     */
    
    var destType = typeof(TResult);
    var destConstructor = destType.GetConstructors()[0];
    var constructorParams = destConstructor.GetParameters();
    var sourceProperties = srcType.GetProperties().ToDictionary(p => p.Name);
    var sourceParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "obj");
    var typedSourceParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(srcType, "source");
    var convertObjToSourceExpression = Expression.Convert(sourceParameterExpression, srcType);
    var assignToSourceTypeExpression = Expression.Assign(
        typedSourceParameterExpression, 
        convertObjToSourceExpression);
    var callConstructorArgumentExpressions = constructorParams
        .Select(param => Expression.Property(
            typedSourceParameterExpression, 
            sourceProperties[param.Name!]))
        .Cast<Expression>()
        .ToArray();
    var callConstructorExpression = Expression.New(destConstructor, callConstructorArgumentExpressions);
    var returnTarget = Expression.Label(destType);
    var lambdaBodyExpression = Expression.Block(new[] { typedSourceParameterExpression }, 
        assignToSourceTypeExpression, 
        Expression.Label(returnTarget, callConstructorExpression));
    var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, TResult>>(
        lambdaBodyExpression, 
        sourceParameterExpression);

    return lambdaExpression.Compile();
}
```